# `.' cannot appear in a constant-expression

Tags: c++, templates

I'm getting the following error:

```
`.' cannot appear in a constant-expression
```

for this function (line 4):

```
    bool Covers(const Region<C,V,D>& other) const {
        const Region& me = *this;
        for (unsigned d = 0; d < D; d++) {
            if (me[d].min > other[d].min || me[d].max < other[d].max) {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

can anyone explain the problem please?

**EDIT:**

the definition of Region is:

```
template <typename C, typename V, unsigned D>
class Region : public boost::array<Detail::Range<C>,D>
```

when `Range` has a `min` and `max` variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying out your code tells me, that the compiler has a problem with the `me[d].max < other[d].max` part. So the problem with the dot was bogus. Instead the compiler has a problem with the comparison operator. Just reverting the comparison made the compiler error magically disappear:

```
if (me[i].min > other[i].min || other[i].max > me[i].max) {
       return false;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If stakx's answer is not sufficient, you may want to look into "min" and "max" variables. There may be some preprocessor definition, preventing the whole thing from working.

Try adding

```
#undef min   
#undef max
```

just before your code, to see if the error stands.

Answer (score 2):

I assume this fails because the `[]` operator is not a valid operation on your variables `me`, `other`, etc.

- Did you **overload the `[]` operator** on your `Region<>` class? If so, does it return an object which actually has these `min` and `max` members? — Does the overloaded operator return an object, an object by reference, or a pointer to an object? (In the last case, you'd need to replace `.` by `->`.)
- If you *haven't* overloaded `[]`, then `me`, `other` etc. would have to be **declared as an array** for your code to be valid.

Comment: `[]` operator is overloaded (inherited from `boost::array`).

Answer (score 0):

This is probably failing because you have not defined operator[](unsigned)const. I would also suggest that you use `std::size_t`or `int` as your loop variable; it is very uncommon to just see `unsigned`. Since you are using an unsigned type, though, the logical choice would be to use `std::size_t`. You could also try invoking this->operator[](d) instead of me[d] just as a sanity-check, although what you have should work fine assuming that your class implements the appropriate operator overload.